# XSLT display email if present

Tags: xslt

I am working on a page that displays contact email and phone number at the bottom of the page. The code I'm using now is:

```
email: <a href="mailto:{//footer_email}">
          <xsl:value-of select="//footer_email"/></a>
```

I just ran across a page that doesn't have an email at the bottom, so when I view the XML document it shows "email: " with nothing after it.

My question is, how would I specify if there is an email present, then display the entire thing, but if there isn't an email present, then don't display it at all.

Comment: Put it into its own template.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a truly XSLT solution that shows how this can be done avoiding any conditional logic at all. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You don't need any conditional logic at all**.

**Simply use:**

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="mailLink" select="(//footer_email)[1]"/>
```

**where you have this template:**

```
<xsl:template match="footer_email" mode="mailLink">
   email: <a href="mailto:{.}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></a>     
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to apply that to a phone number? `<xsl:value-of select="//footer_phone"/>` where the output is `(xxx) xxx-xxxx`?

Comment: @jrottier: Yes, but you need to provide more information -- preferrably in a separate question.

Comment: It was basically the same thing as the email, but I actually just figured it out using the same code you posted above. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Using `xsl:if` you check whether there is `//footer_email` or not:

```
<xsl:if test="//footer_email">
   email: <a href="mailto:{//footer_email}"><xsl:value-of select="//footer_email"/></a>
</xsl:if>
```